# parse_url function php

Tags: php, parsing, url

I'm extracting tlds from my urls content  with php's parse_url.
 than I have an array of top level domains which are compared with the extracted top level domain if they match or not.

```
  $url = parse_url($tag->getAttribute('href'));

  if (in_array($url['host'], $affi_urls) || $url['host'] == "www.example.com"){   

    $tag->setAttribute('href', '/redirect.php?url='.$href);       


   }
```

this works fine if the ur['host'] contains the top level domain. if the url['host'] is a relative path than is a big mess overthere.

```
/redirect.php?url=/example/test
```

how could I avoid this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the hostname of the page that you're processing. If `$url['host']` is empty, use that hostname in its place.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the url parameters.

```
$tag->setAttribute('href', '/redirect.php?url='.urlencode($href));
```

And then after getting the data by `parse_url`, use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the data.